# Asp.net: How to take specific url on website down for sometime?

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect

We have asp.net website and we want have revamped particular section.

example.com has modules like mobile, laptop like:

- example.com/mobile/
- example.com/electronics/

We are revamping the mobile module but the url would remain same i.e. example.com/mobile/. The code is deployed on multiple servers and request is assigned to particular server using load balancer.

The problem is when we take release/new-code on one server, the subsequent request may not go to server that has the new code. How can we handle this situation without modifying the url?

One solution is to:

1. Take 1st release to modify htaccess to temporary redirect incoming request for "example.com/mobile/" to some "maintenance page".
2. Take 2nd release to deploy new code. (keeping htaccess redirecting incoming request for "example.com/mobile/" to some "maintenance page")
3. Take 3rd release to remove this temporary redirection of "example.com/mobile/" to some "maintenance page". (as new code will be on all servers, it would be safe now)

As we have 6 servers and each release take time, is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Just to confirm as you tagged this htaccess - your .net site is hosted on Apache or IIS?

Comment: Why don't you do 2 releases one with a placeholder maintenance page at the location of the to be released update. And the second one with the new page. That way you do not have to fuss with htaccess and each server will operate independently based on the files on the server?

Comment: This is IIS try this [link](https://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiI4LLjzfnVAhXHbhQKHcuRAUoQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iis.net%2Fdownloads%2Fmicrosoft%2Furl-rewrite&usg=AFQjCNGvKrCCm_iZIcfd3q4PvwRFbQU6yQ)